# Access to the list items of IDictionary in RazorPage

Tags: c#, listview, key-value, razor-pages, idictionary

I need to list all ceremonies incase of my searchModel parameters are empty. So When the page loaded, we should have a list of multimedia albums of ceremonies. The following method doing generate this list. but I need to show items of my MultimediaViewList in RazorPage one by one. So I should access to the following items and its values in HTML part of my razor page Id,Title,CeremonyId,Ceremony,FileAddress
How can I do that?

```
public Dictionary<string, List<MultimediaViewModel>> Search(MultimediaSearchModel searchModel)
{
    var query = _hContext.Multimedias.Include(x => x.Ceremony).Select(g => new MultimediaViewModel
    {
        Id = g.Id,
        Title = g.Title,
        CeremonyId = g.CeremonyId,
        Ceremony = g.Ceremony.Title,
        FileAddress = g.FileAddress
    }).GroupBy(g => g.CeremonyId).ToList();
    return query.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());
}
```

this is My View Model:

```
public class MultimediaViewModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get;  set; }
        public string FileAddress { get;  set; }
        public long CeremonyId { get;  set; }
        public string Ceremony { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I think the return type of your method should be a List of MultimediaViewModel, and then return `query.SelectMany(x=> x).Distinct().ToList()`
Also, preferablly you should assign the return value of this method to a property called MultimediaViewList to use it in your razor page.

Comment: As explained, the return type of search method is Dictionary<string, List<MultimediaViewModel>>. Now I need to know how I can display the items of MultimediaViewModel  for example in a foreach loop in my razor page.

Comment: `foreach(var KeyValuePair in Model.Search(Model.MultimediaSearchModel){
   foreach(var item in keyValuePair.Value){
     <p>@item.Title </p>

}
}`

Comment: Sorry but it is not the thing that I want. let me explain more. assume that I have a 10 records. these records reduced through Group by to 6 records. Now I need to make a list including JUST 6 records not 10 records. your answer make a list including Group by items within its childs that is totally 10 records. So I need the MultimediaViewModel items(Id, Title, FileAddress,...) just for Key items not for values of each key item.

Comment: I think with the use of  SelectMany() and Distinct() on the result of your search you would get 6 records.

`foreach(var KeyValuePair in Model.Search(Model.MultimediaSearchModel).SelectMany(x=> x).Distinct()){
<p>@item.Title </p>
}`